# Will the SEO of a webpage suffer if its parent directory has a redirect?

Tags: seo, redirects, subdirectory

I'll have lots of webpages with URLs in this format:

`https://www.example.edu/faculty/firstname-lastname`

but for the parent page...

`https://www.example.edu/faculty`

...I want it to redirect to...

`https://www.example.edu/directory`

Will each faculty member's page be ranked lower because the parent page (`/faculty`) has a redirect on it?

Answer (score 2):

If nobody is linking to the original link, it shouldn't be a big deal for that page. Just make sure to use the correct redirect for what the purpose is (301: temporary, 302: permanent), and correctly handle the details around it. [This link has more details on that.](https://www.semrush.com/blog/301-redirects/?kw=&cmp=CA_SRCH_DSA_Blog_Core_BU_EN&label=dsa_pagefeed&Network=g&Device=c&utm_content=515816513168&kwid=dsa-1057183192075&cmpid=11775480152&agpid=117404300314&BU=Core&extid=23626511299&adpos=&gclid=Cj0KCQjwio6XBhCMARIsAC0u9aG4Rmh_uR2MaGN-76fWrM7QwirRVlgnpPHZD5K94hDSK8X3wKgW-xMaAsdCEALw_wcB)

Also, redirecting that page shouldn't affect the children as they are not necessarily considered part of the original url. They are separate pages completely, just happen to include that location as part of the url. You aren't changing those URLs.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I'm thinking I'm thinking I'll need to put a meta refresh redirect on this page: https://www.college.edu/faculty because if I put a 301 redirect on it, our .htaccess fill will treat it as a wildcard redirect and forward https://www.college.edu/faculty/firstname-lastname to https://www.college.edu/directory/firstname-lastname.  Would the meta refresh make any difference?  I'm assuming not, based on your 2nd paragraph.

Comment: Do NOT use a meta refresh redirect unless: 1) you cannot use an .htaccess file -  in case, for instance, you are using a CMS which periodically overwrites your .htaccess file; 2) you want to redirect only a single file in a directory with multiple files. In other cases, it can lead to issues with user disorientation, or your site could be considered as spam as those redirects are typically used by spammers.

Answer (score -1):

If there is trust on the page and already referring other sites, it can give a negative signal.

Comment: Trust for which URL, the page or its parent directory?

Comment: What negative signal would it give?  Do you have a reference to back up this claim?

Comment: Trust on what page?  The current links in use are www.college.edu/directory and www.college.edu/acdemics/centers/center-name/faculty/firstname-lastname.  I'll need to redirect that long URL to www.college.edu/faculty/firstname-lastname and create a new page for www.college.edu/faculty which redirects to www.college.edu/directory.  I'm just wondering if this creates and negative SEO impact by redirecting from /faculty to /directory